# iTerm2 printing out a null character

Tags: macos, terminal

Every time a command I issue from iTerm2 takes longer than a minute to complete, a null character ^@ gets printed out once for every minute or so continuously until the process completes.

I can't figure out if this is a bug or a feature that I should somehow be able to disable.

It actually seems to print out to the terminal, but it is not going to either stdout or stderr:

```
$ echo `sleep 181`
^@^@
$ echo `sleep 181` 2> /tmp/stderr
^@^@
$ echo `sleep 181` > /tmp/stdout
^@^@
```

Comment: Does this happen in any other terminal? What shell are you using? With the latest beta and the fish shell, I can't reproduce this.

Comment: I have not seen this with the Terminal app. I've only ever seen it happen with iTerm2. For a sanity check, I will see if it happens with regular iTerm. I'm using bash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn off "when idle send ascii code" in prefs->profiles->session.

Comment: but I still get `^@%` when i open the iterm2 first time, why?